# Create "new pages" within the admin section of plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

Here is my situation, I'm trying to create my first plugin for Wordpress, but I'm having an issue of trying to change the display within the plugin admin page.

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

As you can see I have a couple links on the new page. What I want to do is to change what is being displayed in the window when I click on a link.

If this has been asked, I'm sorry, please point me to the post, but I'm not sure how to word what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to change the view based on links that are clicked. So if I wanted to add a customer, I could click on the 'Add Customer' link, and the display a form to add the user, all the while maintaining the admin portion (the links of the left).

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You need to add a query to your link then check it with `$_GET` in your php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add another $_GET parameter to the URL. In the moment you are viewing `admin.php?page=Customer_Search`. You could make your links go like `admin.php?page=Customer_Search&type=your-page`.

In your plugins files you can then output the desired content based on that parameter.

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'your-page') {
   //output your page ...
}elseif( ....other pages ...
```

Comment: I think that about did it! Thank you for the help!